# Why does Print(builder) not work when Writeline(builder) does?

Tags: vb.net, printing, console.writeline

I'm working on an online compiler and this code works:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For i As Integer = 1 to 54    
        builder.Append(i & " = " & ConvertToLetter(i) & vbCrLf)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(builder)
End Sub
```

However, if you replace Console.WriteLine with "Print" I get this error when compiling:

/home/cg/root/main.vb (11,11) : error VBNC30518: CHANGEME

Could anyone explain why this is the case? By the way, if it helps you any, ConvertToLetter is Microsoft's generic Convert(Column) To Letter function. It returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different functions:

Console.Writeline -> String Output to the console

Print -> Writes display-formatted data to a sequential file

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264278.aspx

Comment: I definitely see the difference now... I tried it with PrintLine as well and I'm given the same error though.

Answer (score 1):

You have vba and vb.net so i'm not sure what you are looking for exactly. If you are looking to print it to the immediate window in VBA you can use

```
Debug.Print builder
```

Although there is no stringbuilder in VBA so you will have to handle that as a string.

To get a letter from a number in VBA you can use this

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

In VB.NET you can do

```
Debug.Print(builder)
```

you have to use

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
```

Here is some more info for VB.NET here is more info.

[How do I output code while debugging in Visual Basic 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490228/how-do-i-output-code-while-debugging-in-visual-basic-2010)

Here is a vb.net conver to letter function that i use.

```
private String Number2String(int number, bool isCaps)
{
    Char c = (Char)((isCaps ? 65 : 97) + (number - 1));
    return c.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I am using code in a VB.NET compiler, although it's based on VBA code I had build. The code I'm having trouble with is VB.NET. Sorry for the misunderstanding. 

Additionally, that Letter function is pretty cool, I'll check it out soon. Does it work for triple Letter Column names as well as double letter?

Comment: Are you trying to output to immediate window for debug or to a file?

Comment: Outputting to a Dimensional Variable. I'm using it to say:

Range(ConvertToLetter(1) & "1", ConvertToLetter(x) & y).Select

Kind of thing